rrsync command in authorized_keys refers to non-existing dir
I want to restrict rsync using the command option to the ``rrsyncscript inauthorized_keys`:
command="rrsync -ro /home/server_backup",restrict ssh-ed25519 AAA...

But when calling rsync from the client, the program tries to change to the non-existing dir /home/server_backup/home/server_backup:
rsync -e ssh -aivvv --human-readable server1:/home/server_backup/ /var/backup/server1
opening connection using: ssh server1 rsync --server --sender -vvvlogDtpre.iLsfxCIvu . /home/server_backup/
receiving incremental file list
rsync: [sender] change_dir "/home/server_backup/home/server_backup" failed: No such file or directory (2)

I guess the rrsync argument on the server is somehow combined with the source argument to rsync on the client – but how and why?

This answer says you have to give a path relative to the restricted directory.

Thank you – I saw the answer, but overlooked the reference to relative paths!
